# Is the Nothing child class of any other class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following Code A is from the project architecture-samples at https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

The function `getTasks()` will return `Result<List<Task>>`.

The class `data class Error(val exception: Exception)` will return `Result<Nothing>()`.

I think the code  `Error(e)`  will cause error because it can't return `Result<List<Task>>`.

Is the Nothing child class of any other class in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
class TasksLocalDataSource internal constructor(
    private val tasksDao: TasksDao,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksDataSource {
    ...
   override suspend fun getTasks(): Result<List<Task>> {
        return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            try {
                Success(tasksDao.getTasks())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Error(e)                   //I think that it will be cause error
            }
        }
    }
   ...
}


interface TasksDao {
  ...
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Tasks")
  suspend fun getTasks(): List<Task>
   ...
}

sealed class Result<out R> {

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>()

    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
            is Error -> "Error[exception=$exception]"
            Loading -> "Loading"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "child" class, I'm assuming you mean *sub*type? If so, yes `Nothing` is indeed a subtype of every other type in Kotlin. Its the opposite analog of `Any?` which is the *super*type of every type in Kotlin.

`Nothing` is what allows functions like `TODO()` to work. The implementation of this function is:

```
public inline fun TODO(): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError()
```

indicating that `TODO()` *never returns anything* i.e. it always throws an exception at runtime. This is what allows `TODO()` to be placed into any context. For example:

```
fun foo(): String = TODO()
```

compiles without any error even though `TODO()` does not return a `String` , because the compiler knows `TODO()` will never return anything (more specifically, `Nothing` is a subtype of `String` and therefore "returns" a valid type in that expression).

Now, getting to your question:

> I think the code `Error(e)` will cause error because it can't return `Result<List<Task>>`.

We noted that `Nothing` *is indeed* a subtype of every other type.

We must also note that the definition of the sealed `Result` class i.e. `Result<out R>` uses the [variance annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) `out`. This means that the type parameter `T` of `Result` is always only **returned** from `Result`, and never consumed by `Result` i.e. `Result` is covariant in `T`. Quoting the Kotlin documentation:

> The general rule is: when a type parameter `T` of a class `C` is declared out, it may occur only in **out**-position in the members of `C`, but **in return `C<Base>` can safely be a supertype of `C<Derived>`**.

Combining this rule with the knowledge that `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type, this allows `Error(e)` which implements `Result<Nothing>` to be a valid return value of `Result<List<Task>>`, and therefore there is no error in the line of code you indicated.